# Using the values in compiled python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyc

I want to connect to MySQL using python and want to hide the login credentials. For that I have created a compiles python .pyc file which has two strings. I want to use these strings in another python file. The code of python file which i converted to .pyc is below.

```
import os

dbuser = os.environ.get('UN')
dbpswd = os.environ.get('PW')
```

how do i import dbuser and dbpswd values in another python file.

Comment: It doesn't work like that :). These are done at run time :). The compiled code doesn't have the credentials :). It just have the bytecode which the virtual machine just runs. But like any other, you just do `from yourmodule import dbuser, dbpswd`. But still you are not hiding anything with the `.pyc` file :)

Comment: I'm confused, how are you "hidding" the credentials when they are environmental variables?

Comment: thank you han solo. code in the questionis python code. i ahve converyted that python code to byte code.

Comment: is there any other way to hide the credentials

Comment: Hide the credentials as in how exactly ? Your source code never has the credentials, if that is what you are asking. You are just getting it from the environment of the parent process

Comment: What do you mean by hide? Do you simply wish to obfuscation?

Comment: hiding means, anyone should not see the credentials. yes, i agree by using environment variables they cannot be hidden. is there any other way to hide the login credentials.

Comment: Can you please be more specific, do you mean people that have access to view enviroment variables should not see the plain text username/password?

Comment: my aim is to do not reveal the admin login credentials to anybody. that can be in any method. using environment variables is not mandatory